# how to broadcast event called by job class

Tags: laravel, events, jobs, broadcast

In a Laravel project i am trying to broadcast a event named "closed" via pusher.

In my controller i am calling:

```
App\Jobs\Closing::dispatch();
```

My App\Jobs\Closing.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\Jobs\Close;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
class Closing implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct(){}
    public function handle()
    {
        $delay = mt_random(10,20);
        Close::dispatch()->delay(now()->addSeconds($delay));
    }
}
```

My app\Jobs\Close.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\Events\Closed;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
class Close implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct(){}
    public function handle()
    {
        event(new Closed());
    }
}
```

My App\Events\Closed.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Events;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
class Closed implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct(){}
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['updates'];
    }
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'closed';
    }
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => 'Is Closed!'];
    }
}
```

At this point i need to explain two mandatory situations.

The first one is that i needed to create the job Close class as a job because i needed to delay the execution of the task close. And the only way i can see to make this "delay" is with a Job Class.

The second one is that i have chosen to implement "ShouldBroadcastNow" instead of "ShouldBroadcast" in the event Closed class because i don't want to queue the broadcasting.

Now the problem is that after running:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1
```

i get in the following output on Command Console:

Processing: App\Jobs\Closing

Processed: App\Jobs\Closing

Processing: App\Jobs\Close

Processing: App\Events\Closed

Failed: App\Events\Closed

Failed: App\Jobs\Close

The first thing that i find weird is that App\Events\Closed goes to queue despite the fact that it implements "ShouldBroadcastNow".

On laravel.log it seems that it occurred a BroadcastException at PusherBroadcaster.php.

But if in the Controller i do:

```
event(new App\Events\Closed());
```

the event is properly broadcast via pusher to the client browser.

What is going wrong?

Is there other way do delay the "close" without jobs?

The purpose is to have the following workflow:

1 - We have a event named "closing" an another event named "closed";

2 - We have a task named "close" that occurs "x" seconds after the event "closing", where "x" is a random number;

3 - After the execution of "close" task we broadcast the event "closed".

Thank you for your attention to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile i found this is a already known issue (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478).

It can be solved in two ways:

1 - editing the relevants php.ini files (in my case it was mamp/conf/php7.0.9/php.ini and mamp/bin/php/php7.0.9/php.ini) to point at the location of curl certificate;

2 - editing config/broadcasting.php (setting encrypted to false in pusher options).